# XDoclet, a dead tool?

Tags: java, eclipse, xdoclet

I am using the latest Eclipse for Java EE & the latest JBoss Tools plugin.
Now, I am working on some EJB 2.x code.

I cannot find a way to generate the xdoclet-build.xml file like before.

After some investigations, I begin to ask myself (and you) that is XDoclet still supported by the community: JBoss, Eclipse (WTP), etc. ?

If yes, what is now the good way to use XDoclet to generate my old-style EJB Homes & Interfaces?

Can XDoclet work using Java 5 style code?

Thanks
Alban.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's no longer supported, so you would have to maintain your build yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a bit late, but concerning your question about **Java 5**, I managed to make it work with Maven and [xdoclet-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/xdoclet-maven-plugin/).
The problem was in **XJavadoc**. I downloaded the patched version (xjavadoc-1.1-j5-v4.jar) [there](https://xdoclet.onjira.com/browse/XJD-41), installed it in my local Maven repo, and used it on xdoclet plugin :

```
<!-- PLUGIN XDOCLET -->
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>xdoclet-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xdoclet</groupId>
            <artifactId>xjavadoc</artifactId>
            <version>1.1-j5-v4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

XDoclet is not *totally* dead, it's still used on legacy J2EE (1.3, 1.4) applications, not yet migrated towards Java EE 5+.

References :

- [XDoclet for JDK 5](http://raibledesigns.com/rd/entry/xdoclet_for_jdk_5) (from Raible Designs)
- [Support Java 1.5 Syntax ?](https://xdoclet.onjira.com/browse/XJD-41) (issue fixed)
- [Java 1.5](https://xdoclet.onjira.com/browse/XJD-67) (issue open)