# Generate EJB 2.x interfaces

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb-2.x

to follow my previous question: [XDoclet, a dead tool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2560272/xdoclet-a-dead-tool)
what tool can I use nowadays to generate the homes & interfaces of my EJB's?

Thanks by advance,
Alban.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still use XDoclet (explicitly call your build file), unless you move to EJB3, where you no longer need them.

Comment: I saw it...
But, to my understanding, it's only a patch for the xjavadoc part (I need the EJBDoclet) and this patch have never been promote as official code...

Comment: Sorry thelost!

I just made it using the link you provide.
It's not clear for me, but it works :)
Thanks.